# Azure Search Suggestions API - no results for out of order keywords

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have an item with the title "1998 John Deere 935" in my search index. The suggestions API will not return any results for "John 935", but the search API will. Neither API request has fuzzy=true.

Do I have to enable fuzzy search to make this work for suggestions? I'm really hoping not, since that dramatically increases search time.

Comment: @Yahnoosh can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure Search [suggesters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/suggesters) only support [infix matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/suggesters#usage) for finding suggestion candidates. Infix matching performs flexible matching of phrases at the beginning or in the middle of sentences, which isn’t what you are looking for.

Here are two other options:

1. Combine the Search API with the [edgeNGram_v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search#token-filters-reference) token filter when you index data. This could help with partial or incomplete matches. You can learn more about how to use this token filter with the [custom analyzers documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search#overview)
2. You can use the [Proximity Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_proximity) feature to find terms which are near each-other in a query.

Please let me know if you need additional clarification or have more questions.

Thanks,
Matt